# Gitlab configuration to let users run pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I just installed a private gitlab-ce instance with docker compose.
I registered two runners for the instance and created an other admin user (aka admin2).

If admin2 creates a project and add a pipeline configuration, he can't validate the pipeline : graphql request `getCiConfigData` returns this response `{...{ message: "The resource that you are attempting to access does not exist or you don't have permission to perform this action...}`

And the project pipeline view never displays the "RUN Pipeline" blue button.

The strange behavior is that the admin created at the installation has access to pipeline and can run it.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out why.
Only confirmed user can access pipelines, and the user I created with a curl request was not confirmed.

I confirmed user manually with the first admin account and now all is working fine.